# Decomposition of sum of two independent random variables

Tags: statistics, expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two indpenent r.v.
How can I get an expression for:

$$E[X|X+Y=a]$$

where $a$ is a constant?
In other words, is there a general rule to recover the expected value of $X$ when all I know is the value of the sum $X+Y$?
Similarly, what is

$$E[X|X+Y<a] $$

Would it be easier to answer these questions if $X$ and $Y$ are not only independently but also identically distributed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., $E(X\mid X+Y)=E(Y\mid X+Y)$ by symmetry hence $$E(X\mid X+Y)=\tfrac12(X+Y).$$ When $X$ and $Y$ are independent with possibly different distributions, there is no similar simple formula independent on the distributions.
Even when $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., there exists no general formula for $E(X\mid X+Y\lt a)$, except, by the same argument, the semi-explicit identity
$$E(X\mid X+Y\lt a)=\tfrac12E(X+Y\mid X+Y\lt a).$$

Comment: The first one does not require independence, just symmetry, no?

Comment: @leonbloy Quite true, but symmetry in the sense that (X,Y) and (Y,X) are identically distributed, not only that X and Y are.